# Desorden en CategoryPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-settings

Tengo una enorme duda acerca de los CategoryPreferences y ScreenPreferences y viendo en foros aplico lo que se muestra pero en mi caso al copilar la actividad de configuración se muestra de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las lineas Roja representan la posición de los dividers que me pinta y los Azules son los dividers donde quiero que aparezcan adjunto  mi código fuente:

```
  <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/Basico"
        >
        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="pref_envio"
            android:title="@string/TypeSend"
            android:summaryOn="@string/TypeSendDescripcionON"
            android:summaryOff="@string/TypeSendDescripcionOFF"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>
        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="prf_notas"
            android:title="@string/ObservacionesTitulo"
            android:summaryOn="@string/ObservacionesDescripcionON"
            android:summaryOff="@string/ObservacionesDescripcionOFF"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/Account">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="save_account"
            android:title="@string/AccountTitulo"
            android:summaryOff="@string/AccountDescripcionOFF"
            android:summaryOn="@string/AccountDescripcionON"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_save_black_24dp"
            />

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="pref_usu"
            android:title="@string/Usuario"
            android:summary="@string/UsuarioDescripcion"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/UsuarioDialog"
            android:editable="false"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            />
        <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="@string/AcountUpdate"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit_black"
            android:singleLineTitle="true">

        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/informacion"
        >
        <Preference
            android:title="@string/InformacionVersion">
        </Preference>

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Entonces no se a que se deba que no me esta organizando las secciones cómo debe de ser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He copiado el `PreferenceScreen` que tienes y los dividers me han salido correctamente, tan solo no he podido colocar los mismos strings e iconos ya que no tengo esos recursos te dejo el código que he probado en [GitHub](https://github.com/israteneda/StackOverflow/tree/master/PreferencesScreen).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Crees que se deba al tema que este implementado? El mio me lo muestra  super raro

Comment: Posiblemente puede ser el tema, podrías subir tu código a GitHub para probarlo y ver si me muestra igual que a ti o podrías pobrar el código que he colocado en GitHub a ver si te sigue mostrando desordenado.

Comment: Hola israteneda me disculpo por no dar una respuesta pronta, si como lo mencionas, es el diseño del tema que estoy usando para mi app, ya que hice otro y el tema default que me android studio no me genera ese diseño.